# Hook recv and unreadable buffer

Tags: c#, sockets, easyhook

I have an application that shows a WebBrowser component, which contains a flash application that create a XMLSocket with a server.
I'm now trying to hook recv ( luckly a LocalHook) for log purpuse, but when I try to read the socket content I get only strange chars, but if i set the hook with SpyStudio I get readable strings.
Here is the code I use :

1. I set the hook with

   ```
   CreateRecvHook = LocalHook.Create(
       LocalHook.GetProcAddress("ws2_32.dll", "recv"),
       new Drecv(recv_Hooked),
       this);


   CreateRecvHook.ThreadACL.SetExclusiveACL(new Int32[] { 0 });
   ```
2. I set up everything I need with

   ```
   [DllImport("ws2_32.dll")]
   static extern int recv(
               IntPtr socketHandle,
               IntPtr buf,
               int count,
               int socketFlags
       );


   [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall,
       CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
       SetLastError = true)]


   delegate int Drecv(
               IntPtr socketHandle,
               IntPtr buf,
               int count,
               int socketFlags
       );


   static int recv_Hooked(
               IntPtr socketHandle,
               IntPtr buf,
               int count,
               int socketFlags)
   {
       byte[] test = new byte[count];
       Marshal.Copy(buf, test, 0, count);


   IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;


   ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(count);
   Marshal.Copy(test, 0, ptr, count);


   string s = System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(test);
   Debug.WriteLine(s);
   System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("log.txt");
   file.WriteLine(s);


   file.Close();
   return recv(socketHandle, buf, count, socketFlags);;


   }
   ```

I've already tried using different Encoding without success. As a side note, the WebBrowser doesn't seems to have any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're saving the content of the uninitialized buffer, no wonder it's garbage.

There is nothing in that buffer until after `recv` (the real one) fills it in.  You also can't know how many bytes are actually valid except by inspecting the return code from the real `recv`.

Comment: I feel a little dumb, but ... then why when I hook the same function with spystudio ( http://www.nektra.com/products/spystudio-api-monitor/ )  i get readable strings?

Comment: Presumably because SpyStudio knows about the parameters and reads them at the right time: input parameters are read before calling the real function, and return value and output parameters are captured after calling the real function.  Hooking a function is a lot like overriding a method... and a overriding method needs to do part of its work before calling the base class implementation and part after, a tail call isn't always the right thing to do.